# Facebook login issue unable to get user's actual facebook id

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

We have an app available in android, ios and web. The app uses facebook login(using [easyfacebook.jar](http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/download.asp)) as alternate way of authorizing users. It was working fine but due to recent changes in facebook sdk I am unable to get the actual facebook id as the facebook api returns app-specific user id. From the [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) page:

> Changes from v1.0 to v2.0
>
> App-scoped User IDs: To better protect people's information, when
>   people log into a version of your app that has been upgraded to use
>   Graph API v2.0, Facebook will now issue an app-scoped ID rather than
>   that person's orginal ID. However, for users that have previously
>   logged into your app, the user ID will not change.

The id that I am getting are different for ios, web and android. Please take a look:

**ios and web** https://www.facebook.com/559709594 //return's actual userID

**Android** https://www.facebook.com/10152580446094595 //not returning actual userId

I tried the official facebook sdk to get the actual user id but it was not successful. I am trying to get user id using the following way:

```
user = graphApi.getMyAccountInfo();
            facebookIdLogin = user.getId();
            //returns app specific id not actual user id id = 10152580446094595 
            Log.d("username is : ", user.getName());//return actual value
            Log.d("facebook id is this", facebookIdLogin);
            Log.d("facebook user link", user.getLink());
            //returns www.facebook.com/10152580446094595
```

Is there any way for me to get the actual userId. I need the actual userId because of synchronization between the platforms. Whatever I do I am only getting the app specific userId. Here's the permission I am requesting:

```
String permissions[] = { "public_profile", "user_friends", "email" };
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing is the difference between an app-scoped user_id which was introduced with the Graph API v2.0, and the global user_id.

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids for the details.

Comment: I figured that out after cracking my head for a while. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question was just a misunderstanding. All the versions were receiving profile id different than the actual profile id. In android I had a separate dashboard configured so I was receiving different id. 
**Note the id will be same for the same project in the same dashboard with same account.**. Hope this helps someone.