# Why I am not geting same Facebook Ids for same account of my app(Android) and website (PHP)?

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having issue while fetching Fb Id from `Graph Search 2.0 API` .

For the same account I am getting two different fb Id. I want to have a single ID, from android App and website (PHP).

Android : **100003767313938**
PHP web : **491515637650676**

I need to make both same.
Please suggest , How can I get both same fb id ?

Comment: `I need to make both same` How will we know what are you doing without the code.? Post the code that you have tried

Comment: I think your PHP web return correct one but android return secrete id.

Comment: Thank you haresh . I think I am facing issue in android. Because It generates older versioned id. FB has upgraded user Ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you probably have your **android app** and your **facebook app** configured in a separate project in facebook dashboard. Facebook sends **App-scoped User IDs** to any external requests. See my answer in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544741/facebook-login-issue-unable-to-get-users-actual-facebook-id). Also have a look at [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids). The solution is to make android and webserver application inside the same project and adding platform web and android.

**Update**

Under Settings-> Add Platform add your required platforms
[image]

Comment: I am using GRAPH SEARCH 2.0 fpr PHP and SDKs for android. So Is this the reason why It happens ? and where I nedd to change ? In web or android ?

Comment: @RonakPatel see the edited answer select website and android from the above image

Comment: @RonakPatel thanks I was cracking my head when my app suddenly didnot work which was working so harmonously before. Glad to help